# Reading file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, file

I have a problem reading the stats of a file. I have this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
var chunk = process.stdin.read();
if (chunk !== null) {
   var stats =fs.statSync(chunk);
   length=stats.size;
   console.log(length);
 }
});
```

When I exec this code I get this error:

```
return binding.stat(pathModule._makeLong(path));
             ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'hello.txt
```

But the problem is that "hello.txt" actually exists at the same directory¡
I have tried with other files and I always get the same error.
Any ideas?

Thanks¡

Comment: Where's the `'` after `hello.txt`? Have you got a new line character in your filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chunk read from the standard input contains a new line in the end, which was conflicting with your call to `fs.statSync`. Try this:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
var chunk = process.stdin.read();
if (chunk !== null && chunk !== '') {
   var stats = fs.statSync(chunk.trim()); // trim the input
   length=stats.size;
   console.log(length);
 }
});
```

Also note that the function will be constantly executed for as long as 'readable' events are triggered. You may wish to terminate the program at some point or anything like that.